# Scanning a list

Tags: python

I need to scan a list in Python. I'm able to load it from file and do simple operation, but I was trying to do the following:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Starting from the first element I want to produce the following output:

```
1
  2,3,4,5,6,7,8
  3,4,5,6,7,8
  4,5,6,7,8
  5,6,7,8
  6,7,8
  7,8
  8
2
  3,4,5,6,7,8
  4,5,6,7,8
  5,6,7,8
  6,7,8
  7,8
  8
3
  4,5,6,7,8
  5,6,7,8
  6,7,8
  7,8
  8
4
  5,6,7,8
  6,7,8
  7,8
  8
```

and so on.

I was trying something like this:

```
fo = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
L = fo.readlines()
for i in range(len(L)):
    print str(L[i])
    for j in range(len(L)-1-i):
        print '...' + str(L[i+j+1])
```

Could you help me ?

Comment: I am confused... You are printing the list starting from 1,3,4,5,6,7 and 8, then starting with 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, then 3, 5, 7... I don't see the pattern, can you make it explicit?

Comment: I'd just like to add that it would be better to do `with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as fo:
# do stuff with fo` because this way the file is automatically closed even if an error occurs when dealing with it. Just good practice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How's this? Nice and simple to read:

```
>>> for i, j in enumerate(L):
...     print L[i]
...     temp = map(str, L[j:])
...     while temp:
...             print ' ', ','.join(temp)
...             temp = temp[1:]
... 
1
  2,3,4,5,6,7,8
  3,4,5,6,7,8
  4,5,6,7,8
  5,6,7,8
  6,7,8
  7,8
  8
2
  3,4,5,6,7,8
  4,5,6,7,8
  5,6,7,8
  6,7,8
  7,8
  8
3
  4,5,6,7,8
  5,6,7,8
  6,7,8
  7,8
  8
...
```

---

`while temp` means while the list `temp` is not empty. We have to call `map(str, L[j:])` here because the list is full of integers (and thus the `str.join` method would not work)

---

Just another note, it's more pythonic to use a `with` statement when working with files:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as fo:
    L = fo.readlines()
```

Comment: Very nice, but is it what the user wants? See my comment above.

Comment: @Jblasco It seems to be identical to the output he provided in his question

Comment: Although you should probably do `temp = map(str, L[j:])` once and not do it everytime you want to format. :)

Comment: @SukritKalra Good idea! And thank you for the *two* badges :)

Comment: @Haidro : Nice answers deserve the badges. :)

Comment: this algorithm could be slow for long lists, http://stackoverflow.com/a/18041230/1744834 - here some timings

Answer (score 4):

While Haidro answer produces desired output, I should say that this is pretty inefficient algorithm to do the task provided.

quick analysis:

```
for i, j in enumerate(L):          # loop number 1, for i from 1 to N
    print L[i]
    temp = map(str, L[j:])         
    while temp:                    # nested loop number 2, for j from i to N
        print ' ', ','.join(temp)  # nested loop number 3, for k from j to N
        temp = temp[1:]
```

it's too much work for such a simple task. I think it could be made much simplier and faster, joining string just once and then print substrings (as DCM mentioned in comments, to be able to print arbitrary numbers we should precalculate positions of the elements in the string):

```
s = ",".join(map(str, l))                  # creating string
p = [len(str(x)) + 1 for x in l]           # calculating length of each element
p = [sum(p[:i]) for i in range(len(p))]    # calculating positions with rolling total
for i in range(len(l)):                    # loop number 1
    print l[i]
    for j in range(i + 1, len(l)):         # nested loop number 2
        print ' ', s[p[j]:]
```

Here's quick profile of execution times (I've create function `worker1` with Haidro code and `worker2` with mine). You can see how the grows time of execution when you increase input length N:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit

>>> timeit("worker1(l)", "from testSO import worker1, l", number=10)
0.0016222212978796024
>>> timeit("worker1(l*10)", "from testSO import worker1, l", number=10)
0.33153371422580324
>>> timeit("worker1(l*100)", "from testSO import worker1, l", number=10)
163.25908817145972
```

It grows like `O(N^3)`

```
>>> timeit("worker2(l)", "from testSO import worker2, l", number=10)
0.0006974355000011201
>>> timeit("worker2(l*10)", "from testSO import worker2, l", number=10)
0.03448374103493279
>>> timeit("worker2(l*100)", "from testSO import worker2, l", number=10)
4.446190059150922
```

This one grows like `O(N^2)`

It's not that I think that original question looks like performance critical task, but I think it would be nice if people see why algorithm provided could be slower than they expecting.

Comment: This has better performance but is considerably less robust as written.  If the length of the numbers isn't always 1, it won't give the expected results.

Comment: @DSM changed the answer with precomputed positions of the elements